# Magento Different Websites & Catalogues - One Installation

Tags: multistore

Im running a magento installation that has 2 websites that share the same catalogue and the same admin-user access.
How can I use the same installation for creating other websites with different catalogues and make every one of them private ? 

[ Private means without seeing any trace of other shops running on the same installation ]

Any information is appreciated!

Comment: while this is off-topic on SO, you could phrase this better and have better luck on magento.SE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) This is a Magento Enterprise edition feature. We are running a Magento EE instance that is running several different websites (Yes Magento websites) and they don't have a clue about eachother.

I believe the module is called GWS.

2) You could try [this module](http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_advanced_permissions.html) (Advanced Permissions for Community Edition) which appears to be offering the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your interest in answering to my question. Your solution is viable but I'd use it as a last option. I'm too confortable with the Community Edition for the moment.

Comment: Add a second option which allows you to stay with the Community edition ;)

Comment: A little bit offtopic : you say Enterprise Edition has this build in functionality or it does need other extension that I have to buy ?

Comment: Magento EE has this functionality by default.

Comment: And I can take advantage of it even by using Magento EE in CE mode? Will CE templates also work on it? :)

Comment: Yes you could. Just copy the code and layout ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot then! I'll try Magento EE as soon as possible.

Comment: If you use shared customer on a global scope and use an admin user with restricted website scope, you will not be able to see/edit all customers in backend.

Answer (score 3):

Each website must have at least one store (do not confuse with store-view). And each one of these stores must have a 'Root category'.
In order to have 2 separate websites with different products, you should create 2 root categories, and for each store (one in every website) you should assign different root categories. A product can be in one or more websites. You can set this at product level in the tab called '*Websites*'.
You can also set the customer account scope to '*Website*' from system->configuration->customer account.
Each store must have at least one store view, and you can change the theme at store view level from system->configuration->design.
I think this is what you need to make it work.

Comment: How about the users then? Can I create some administrators with limited access to take care of their own website / store and see nothing beyond their website / store scope? 

Few directions please?

Thanks!

Comment: You can do that only with EE. Community Edition does not offer this feature.